# Django Polls tutorial - Admin list filter error

Tags: django

I'm working on the polls tutorial for Django and I can't seem to get the list filter to work. The instruction on the tutorial is simply to add the following line to QuestionAdmin:

list_filter = ['pub_date']

When I do python manage.py runserver on Terminal, I get this:

ERRORS:
: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'question_text', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'QuestionAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'polls.Question'.

: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'pub_date', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'QuestionAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'polls.Question'.

: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'pub_date', which does not refer to a Field.

My code for the polls/admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Choice, Question
# Register your models here.

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('question_text','pub_date','was_published_recently')
    list_filter = ['pub_date']

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

My code for polls/models.py:

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is ...

```
question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

... part from [Writing your first Django app, part 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/)?

BTW this line

`# ...`

means that some code which was previously explained **omitted** but you obviously need it ... so return to [first tutorial page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) and recheck everything ...